# Murata simsurfing: what is the green line

Tags: capacitor, ceramic, graph

I was checking murata simsurfing, and I saw there is a green line next to the blue on for the capacitor graph:

[image: murata simsurf]

The green line on the Resistance-Frequency is also constant, very different from the blue line.

I cannot understand what it represents. The green graph gives me an C, an L and a R, which are constant, not frequency-dependent, so I don't understand what they represent:

[image: murata green]

**=============EDIT==============**

I managed to (partially) figure it out. there is this option on the top left, it switches between simple and precise graph:

[image: simple precise graph green line murata]

But still, what are the C,L,R on the bottom?

[image: CLR murata]

Comment: Provide a hyper link to that page please.

Comment: https://ds.murata.co.jp/simsurfing/mlcc.html?lcid=en-us&jis=false&md5=4806266a4532504909ac36753e6f2fd9 this is the page, there is no direct link for the graphs. (also check my own answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The green line is an RLC circuit model for the part. If you were doing some (spice, etc) modeling you might put those parameters into your model. As you can see from the impedance plot, it is relatively close to the measured data and thus a reasonable approximation that would avoid having to enter the entire table of measured values.